# Filtering VEP annotation file

Tags: sequence-annotation, variant-calling

I am filtering a VEP annotated vcf, trying to maintain just those variants classified as deleterious by `SIFT`and as damaging (probably or possibly included) by `PolyPhen`.

I am using:

```
filter_vep -i "$input" -o "$output" -filter "SIFT = deleterious and PolyPhen match damaging"
```

and I also tried:

```
filter_vep -i "$input" -o "$output" -filter "SIFT match deleterious and PolyPhen match damaging"
```

The output contains just variants with some value in these two fields, but some of the variants are classified as tolerated by `SIFT` and as benign by `PolyPhen`, so do you know why the filter is not working?

As an example: this two variants shouldn't exist in my filtered VCF, because the first one is classified as benign by PolyPhen and the second is classified as benign by both fields:

```
    CHROM  POS  REF  ALT  FILTER  INFO
    1       1934441 .       G       T       .       PASS    deleterious(0.01)|benign(0.138)
    1       207085100       .       G       A       .       PASS   tolerated(0.16)|benign(0.037)
```

As an example of a variant that has pass properly those filters:

```
    CHROM  POS  REF  ALT  FILTER  INFO
    2       3938449 .       T       A       .       PASS    deleterious(0.01)|probably damaging(0.67)
```

Those are 3 variants among those that I have in my filtered VCF, but I should be getting just those variants which are classified as deleterious and damaging by both SIFT and PolyPhen, as the third variant I've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do could be achieved by adding parenthesis to the conditions and by specifying the format of the input file by using the flag `--format vcf`, as specified in the [documentation](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_filter.html).
The final command should look like this:

```bash
filter_vep -i "$input" --format vcf --filter "(SIFT = deleterious) and (PolyPhen match damaging)" -o "$output"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to achieve your goal using the `fuc vcf_vep` [command](https://sbslee-fuc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#vcf-vep) I wrote:

```
$ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'SIFT.str.contains("deleterious") and PolyPhen.str.contains("damaging")' > out.vcf
```

For getting help:

```
$ fuc vcf_vep -h
usage: fuc vcf_vep [-h] [--opposite] [--as_zero] vcf expr

This command will filter a VCF file annotated by Ensemble VEP. It essentially wraps the `pandas.DataFrame.query` method. For details on query expression, please visit the method's documentation page (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query).

examples:
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'SYMBOL == "TP53"' > out.vcf
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'SYMBOL != "TP53"' > out.vcf
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'SYMBOL == "TP53"' --opposite > out.vcf
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'Consequence in ["splice_donor_variant", "stop_gained"]' > out.vcf
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf '(SYMBOL == "TP53") and (Consequence.str.contains("stop_gained"))' > out.vcf
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'gnomAD_AF < 0.001' > out.vcf
  $ fuc vcf_vep in.vcf 'gnomAD_AF < 0.001' --as_zero > out.vcf

positional arguments:
  vcf         Ensemble VEP-annotated VCF file
  expr        query expression to evaluate

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --opposite  use this flag to return records that don’t meet the said criteria
  --as_zero   use this flag to treat missing values as zero instead of NaN
```

You can also do above with Python:

```
from fuc import pyvcf, pyvep
vf = pyvcf.VcfFrame.from_file('in.vcf')
expr = 'SIFT.str.contains("deleterious") and PolyPhen.str.contains("damaging")'
filtered_vf = pyvep.filter_query(vf, expr)
filtered_vf.to_file('out.vcf')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working under a Linux environment, then you may easily use a piped grep search. For example:

```
grep deleterious file.vcf |grep damaging >filtered_file.vcf
```

Comment: The grep output will not be a properly formed VCF.